# Changing a element text based on xhttp.readyState on javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that user clicks and download from a PHP page, since the processing is a little bit long i want to display a text that shows the user that their request is processing, i found the `onreadystatechange` Property can be accessed so maybe I can use it for the task.

```
ready StateHolds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.
     0: request not initialized
     1: server connection established
     2: request received
     3: processing request
     4: request finished and response is ready
```

My code is below, i able the get the `readyState == 4` but cannot get the `readyState == 3`, any advice would be great!

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="weekDL">
  <i class="fa fa-download"></i> 
  Download
</button>
<p id="please">Generating report, please wait..</p>
```

```js
$('#weekDL').on('click',function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#please').show();
  var data = $("#week option:selected").text();

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 3) {
      $('#please').text('Request recieved..');
    } else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      window.location = "PHPexcel/download.php?week=" + data;
      this.responseText;
      $('#please').hide();
      $('#weekDL').show();
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "PHPexcel/download.php?week=" + data, true);
  xhttp.send(); 
});
});
```

Comment: If [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) is available then why you worry about JS code?

Comment: Your code is missing <script>-tags and can not work as it is. Also if you are using jQuery use its ajax-methods like [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine. The issue is because state `3` is only around for a couple of milliseconds before state `4` occurs (depending on the size of the response), therefore your UI update is almost imperceptible.

You can verify this by placing `console.log('state: ' + this.readyState);` within the `onchangereadystate` handler. You will then see the output of all 4 states in the console.

[**Working example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgZoPG)

This is of course assuming that the AJAX request is returning a valid response. If there is an error in the request then you would only see states 1 and 4. However in that case the problem is with the logic in the request, not your JS.

Comment: Thanks sir! the console.log was the key.